# await IAsyncEnumerable<T> where is it used?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, iasyncenumerable

It says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types):

> - Starting with C# 8.0, [`IAsyncEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1), for an async method that
>   returns an *async stream*.

**Question**. In addition to the specified example with `foreach`, is it possible to use more the **`await`** with **`IAsyncEnumerable<T>`** somehow, or is it designed specially for `foreach`? I think yes, but not sure. Perhaps there are other purposes.

```cs
await foreach (var number in GetNumbersAsync())
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}

async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetNumbersAsync()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: As with `IEnumerable` you can call the methods of the interface manually.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, Can you give an example with await? Nothing else is of interest.

Comment: [`GetAsyncEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1.getasyncenumerator?view=net-6.0) returns [`IAsyncEnumerator<int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerator-1?view=net-6.0). You can use the enumerator to manually enumerate an enumerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jeremy Lakeman said in the comments, you can use it however you want. There is nothing magic about it. Simply call `.GetAsyncEnumerator()` on your `IAsyncEnumerable` and then you can use that as you would a regular enumerator, but with async support.

Example:

```cs
IAsyncEnumerator<int> e = GetNumbersAsync().GetAsyncEnumerator();
try
{
  while (await e.MoveNextAsync())
    Console.Write(e.Current + " ");
}
finally {
  if (e != null)
    await e.DisposeAsync();
}
```

The sample was taken from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8

Comment: Or `using (IAsyncEnumerator<int> e = GetNumbersAsync().GetAsyncEnumerator()) { }` instead of the try/catch stuff, though I appreciate you didn't write the sample :)

Comment: Thanks, but everything revolves around the foreach purpose?

Comment: @NikVladi What other use case do you have in mind? There's no `foreach` in the example here. I'm not sure why you'd have an enumerable if you don't want to enumerate it. Can you elaborate on what you're thinking?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar You'd need `await using(..)` in your sample since it is an async disposable :)

Comment: Good point! :-)

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, I'm trying to figure out what await-related end goal is IAsyncEnumerable.

Comment: @NikVladi Imagine that each call to `MoveNextAsync` is actually a web request or database query. While you're waiting for the web service or database to respond, you don't need the thread, right? So making it async allows you to free up a thread pool thread to do something else until the service/database responds.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, That is, I correctly understand that the goal is a convenient asynchronous use of the foreach construct?

Comment: I'd think one of the goals is that, yes.

Answer (score 2):

When compiled, `foreach` becomes like:

```
IAsyncEnumerator<int> e = RangeAsync(10, 3).GetAsyncEnumerator();
try
{
  while (await e.MoveNextAsync()) Console.Write(e.Current + " ");
}
finally { if (e != null) await e.DisposeAsync(); }
```

[Further](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8)

> the [github.com/dotnet/reactive](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) project includes the
> System.Linq.Async library, which provides a full set of such extension
> methods for operating on IAsyncEnumerable. You can include this
> library from NuGet in your project, and have access to a wide array of
> helpful extension methods for operating over IAsyncEnumerable
> objects.